# DATEDIFF and Date Conversion throwing errors

Tags: ssis

I have two dates  (`startdate`,`enddate`) and I need the difference between the two dates using the `datediff` function in an SSIS package.

The start and end dates are in the format `MMDDYYYY`, so first I used derived column to change them into the `'MM/DD/YYYY'` format by using the following `SUBSTRING` function:

```
SUBSTRING(startdate,1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(startdate,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(startdate,5,4)
```

This function worked great in SSMS, but when I use the same function in SSIS it's throwing errors. I also tried to cast the result adding `(DT_DATE)` before the function, still no luck, can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Error message:

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [34]]: Parsing the expression
>   "
>   SUBSTRING(StartDate,1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,5,4)"
>   failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number
>   "32", was not expected.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [34]]: Cannot parse the
>   expression "
>   SUBSTRING(StartDate,1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,5,4)".
>   The expression was not valid, or there is an out-of-memory error.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [34]]: The expression "
>   SUBSTRING(StartDate,1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(StartDate,5,4)"
>   on "output column "StartDate" (62)" is not valid.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [34]]: Failed to set property
>   "Expression" on "output column "StartDate" (62)".

Answer (score 0):

Please use double quotes `("/")` in the SSIS Expression instead of single quotes.